Re-arranging mobius function using recursion
Consider the Mobius function given by
$\Sigma_{d|n}\mu(d)=I(n)\begin{cases}1 & \text{if n=1} \\
0 & \text{if n>1}\end{cases}$.
My book claims that using recursion this formula can somehow be re-arranged into $\mu(n) = -\Sigma_{d|n,d<n}\mu(d)$. I don't know how getting this formula works and am not sure where to start.

Consider the two cases $n = 1$ and $n>1$ this should be direct

(It is much easier than you might think.)
Let us take $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) = I(n)$ as linear equations of infinite variables $\mu(1), \mu(2), \ldots$, and work out those variables one by one.

$n = 1$: We get $\mu(1) = 1$ directly.
$n = 2$: The equation is $\mu(1) + \mu(2) = I(2) = 0$​, and we know $\mu(2) = -\mu(1)$​​.
…
$n = 6$: The equation is $\mu(1) + \mu(2) + \mu(3) + \mu(6) = I(6) = 0$. Note that we have already known $\mu(1),\mu(2),\mu(3)$ above, so just put them to RHS and left the unknown $\mu(6)$ at LHS, i.e. $\mu(6) = - \mu(1) - \mu(2) - \mu(3)$.
…

Generally speaking, when $n > 1$, the equation is $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) = I(n) = 0$. Move $\mu(d)$ where $d < n$ on LHS to RHS, and we get $\mu(n) = - \sum_{d|n,d<n} \mu(d)$.
